# Image links automatically re-written on update

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-3.5

I took over the management of a wordpress site and I'm seriously stumped on what this guy did with this theme.

An image gets posted and it automatically links to itself on a separate page, when i try and change the link it reverts back to linking to itself.

If i remove the link I can not add a new one, it's as if the "add link" button isn't triggering but I can't find a reason why it would do that.

anyone know why this would be happening?